# HTML form with mailto action does not work due to insecure endpoint

Tags: wordpress, forms, mailto, mixed-content, insecure-connection

I am trying to make a wordpress form by typing directly the html code on a template block (that's to match exactly with the visual design required) and it's not working. I receive this error message on chrome console:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://protegetumarcaonline.com/' was
> loaded over a secure connection, but contains a form that targets an
> insecure endpoint 'mailto:proyectosonline@isern.com'. This endpoint
> should be made available over a secure connection.

[https://photos.app.goo.gl/687cUavnacTQ94fF7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQsNG.png)

This is the form code:

```
<form action="mailto:proyectosonline@isern.com" method="get" enctype="text/plain">
        
                            SOBRE TI <br><br>
                            Nombre*<br>
                            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="nombre" required="" class="czr-focusable">
                            Email*<br>
                            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="email" required="" class="czr-focusable">
                            ¿Tienes web?<br>
                            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="web" class="czr-focusable">
                       
                            Marca*
                            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="marca" required="" class="czr-focusable">
                            Productos y/o Servicios de interés*
                            <textarea style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 82px;" name="mensaje" required="" class="czr-focusable">                                </textarea>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Facebook"> Facebook<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Instagram"> Instagram<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Twitter"> Twitter<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Web propia"> Web propia<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Amazon"> Amazon<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Alibaba"> Alibaba<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="Otras"> Otras<br>
                       
                
                            <input type="checkbox" required="" name="politica"> Acepto la política de privacidad*<br>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="comunicaciones"> Acepto recibir comunicaciones comerciales e informativas<br><br>
                            <input type="image" src="wp-content/uploads/2020/11/icono-ENVIAR.png" value="Enviar" name="enviar" alt="Enviar" width="110 style=" border:="" none;"="">
```

I have tried to use method post as well with same result. The website is: https://protegetumarcaonline.com/

What could I do?

Thank you very much,
Miguel Gisbert

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to use "mailto:" with a secure connection, since mailto: opens an application to send the mail. An application that may or may not use a secure protocol (TLS).

One way to fix this would be to use a POST form that calls a PHP script to send mail.
So your HTML looks like something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/wp-content/php_scripts/send_mail.php">
    SOBRE TI <br><br>
    Nombre*<br>
    <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="nombre" required="" class="czr-focusable">
    Email*<br>
    <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="email" required="" class="czr-focusable">
    ¿Tienes web?<br>
    <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="web" class="czr-focusable">        
    Marca*
            <input style="width:100%;" type="text" name="marca" required="" class="czr-focusable">
    Productos y/o Servicios de interés*
    <textarea style="width: 100%; margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; height: 82px;" name="mensaje" required="" class="czr-focusable">                                </textarea>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Facebook"> Facebook<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Instagram"> Instagram<br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="Twitter"> Twitter<br>
    [...]
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

And your PHP file send_mail.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Filter the mail content type.
 */
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );

$message = '<p>Nombre:' . $_POST['nombre'] . '</p><p>Email:' . $_POST['email'] .'</p><p>...</p>';
$result = wp_mail('proyectosonline@isern.com', 'New mail', $message);
if ($result ) {
    // Do something here
}
// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
?>
```

wp_mail doc: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/

wp_mail_content_type: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_content_type/

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas,
I am receiving 500 error now with no message at chrome console.

Comment: I have set all the permissions for the send_mail.php file.
What else could I do? 

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

mailto opens your default mail-sending application. Security of sent message depends on the application and not on the mailto method.

> If you are not sending anything sensitive like bank details or password, you can just click on send anyway button, and the mailto method will proceed as usual.